# Application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way

Tags: java, xml, java-8

I'm try to run a java code and getting the error `"This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way"` and after that this message appears at my console window:

> "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>    what():  basic_string::erase"

OS: Windows 7 (Eclipse Oxygen)

This issue occurs only in `jdk 1.8.0_161 64 bit` and `Windows 7`.

In Windows 10 it works perfectly on:

- All versions of JDK
- `jdk 9 and jdk 7 64 bit` on `Windows 7`.

Comment: Do you use any code fragments that are related to new features of JAVA 9?

Comment: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::erase` is a C++ runtime error message... Do your app uses JNI? Or what?

Comment: can you please post that part of your code

Comment: No sir, i am not using any new feature of java 9  but i am using native method. I dont know why it is working jdk 9 and 7 but not in jdk 8

Answer (score 0):

class classname
{
    static String REQ_XML="\n" +"\n" + "   \n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        caf  ft=new caf();
        if (!ft.open("databasename", "pass"))
            System.err.println("Unable to open data file");
        else {
            System.out.println(ft.requestXml(REQ_XML));
        }

```
}
```

}

Due to this query it is creating a problem.When i dont send the reference in molecule then my jvm got crash.